# trying to use PHP extract() within a function

Tags: php

I have the two following files:

main.php

```
include("functions.php")  
__EXTRACT();  
echo $testvar;
```

functions.php

```
function __EXTRACT(){
extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);
}
```

However, having a form with a textbox called testvar I can't get the extract function to extract the data.. if I remove the function call and insert it the extract statement directly into main.php it works. The include is not a problem as other functions in it works. Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that: in your case `extract()` creates variables **inside** the `__EXTRACT()` function, when the function ends those variables are gone.

Anyway using `extract()` is very rarely a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to do it, so it would create the variable outside the function?

Comment: Use `extract()` directly or, better, use values from `$_POST` without extracting them.

Comment: Hehe, I know that $_POST usage is the best, but this is for rapid prototyping, just wanted to know if it was possible. Thanks again.

Comment: Extract is very good for small projects or prototyping, or anywhere where you have limited data/few columns in your database. EXTR_PREFIX_ALL used with the record name is excellent to solve variable name conflicts. There's no reason why extract() couldn't have an EXTR_DECLARE GLOBAL flag to allow its use inside functions, in my opinion. In the PHP manual for extract() you will see for which arrays it's dangerous to use - for all others, it's a nice and powerful function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this.  This is basically just emulating `register_globals` inside of PHP.  There's a reason it has been off by default for years, and is being removed in 6...